# Draw a picture of primes ideal lying over a prime ideal

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Let $K$ be a number field and $L$ be a finite extension of $K$. Then, let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime in $K$ and $\mathfrak{P}$ be a prime lying over $\mathfrak{p}$. I would like to draw the following picture:

```
      L              \mathfrak{P}             R_L/\mathfrak{P}
      |finite             |unramified                 |extension of
      |extension          |prime                      |finite fields
      K              \mathfrak{p}             R_K/\mathfrak{p}
```

How should I go about it? Can I do it with use `amscd` or `tikz`? Or must I use fancier packages?

Comment: You can definitely do it with TikZ, it is just some nodes with lines between some of them. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Try the package `tikz-cd` ([tag:tikz-cd]).

Comment: I've tried using `array` but the vertical lines look awful. I'm hoping to avoid installing unnecessary packages because I'm on a college computer.

Comment: `tikz-cd` is not unnecessary for this. You can use http://www.writelatex.com to try out the examples.

Comment: I would also recommend `tikz-cd`. If you do anything in algebraic/topological number theory, you will found yourself using commutative diagrams anyways quite soon. And for them, the TikZ library is just perfect :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TikZ solution with a `matrix`. The distance between the entries can be changed with the `column sep` and `row sep` keys. Using `column sep={3cm,between origins}`, the distance is measured from the center of the columns, not the edges. This should ensure that the distance between the lines is the same, regardless of the size of the 'labels' above/below them.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,column sep={3cm,between origins},row sep=2cm] {
    L & \mathfrak{P} & R_L/\mathfrak{P} \\
    K & \mathfrak{p} & R_K/\mathfrak{p} \\};

  \draw (m-1-1) -- node[right,align=left] {finite\\extension} (m-2-1);
  \draw (m-1-2) -- node[right,align=left] {unramified\\prime} (m-2-2);
  \draw (m-1-3) -- node[right,align=left] {extension of\\finite fields} (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No need for tikz.  If you need a longer "stick", more `\mid`s can be added, or just use a `\rule` as I show.  The `\useanchorwidth` setting guarantees that the width of things like `{R_L/\mathfrak{P}}` don't influence the gap to the subsequent text.  The mode `\stackMath` tells `stackengine` to process its arguments in `\textstyle` math by default, whereas `\stackText` indicates to processes stacking arguments as text.  The `\stackalignments` tell whether to align the stack left, center or (not used here) right.

`\stackon` builds up from the baseline, `\stackunder` builds down from the baseline, while `stackanchor` splits the stack across the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\stackMath
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
% FOR SHORTER STICK
%\savestack{\stick}{\stackon[0pt]{\stackunder[0pt]{\mid}{\mid}}{\mid}}
% FOR LONGER STICK
\savestack{\stick}{\rule[-.3in]{.5pt}{.6in}}
\[
\stackMath\def\stackalignment{c}
\stackunder{\stackon{\stick}{L}}{K}
\stackText\def\stackalignment{l}\,
\stackanchor{finite}{extension}
\qquad
\stackMath\def\stackalignment{c}
\stackunder{\stackon{\stick}{\mathfrak{P}}}{\mathfrak{p}}
\stackText\def\stackalignment{l}\,
\stackanchor{unramified}{prime}
\qquad
\stackMath\def\stackalignment{c}
\stackunder{\stackon{\stick}{R_L/\mathfrak{P}}}{R_K/\mathfrak{p}}
\stackText\def\stackalignment{l}\,
\stackanchor{extension of}{finite fields}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `tikz-cd` solution:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}     
    \begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}, row sep = 8ex, column sep = {6em,between origins}]
    L \arrow{d}{\text{\oalign{finite\cr extension}}}& \mathfrak{P} \arrow{d}{\text{\oalign{unramified\cr prime}}} & R_L/\mathfrak{P} \arrow{d}{\text{\oalign{extension of\cr finite fields\hfil}}} \\
    K & \mathfrak{p} & R_K/\mathfrak{p}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of `\oalign`? It knows to be useful: ```L \arrow{d}{\text{\oalign{finite\hfil\cr extension}}}& \mathfrak{P} \arrow{d}{\text{\oalign{unramified\cr prime\hfil}}} & R_L/\mathfrak{P} \arrow{d}{\text{\oalign{extension\cr of finite\hfil\cr fields\hfil}}} \\```

Comment: @tohecz thanks, never used it yet. I adapted my code to this better approach.

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\Prime#1{\mathfrak{#1}}
\def\something(#1)#2#3[#4,#5]{
  \psline(#1,0)(#1,2)
  \uput[270](#1,0){$#2$}
  \uput[90](#1,2){$#3$}
  \uput[0](#1,1){\shortstack[l]{#4\strut\\[-0.75ex] #5\strut}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-0.5)(7,2.5)
  \something(0){K}{L}[finite, extension]
  \something(2.5){\Prime{p}}{\Prime{P}}[unramified, prime]
  \something(5){R_{K}/\Prime{p}}{R_{L}/\Prime{P}}[extension of, finite fields]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, with the venerable `picture` mode (no extra packages required):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\mycenter[1]{\makebox[0pt][c]{#1}}
\newcommand\mylabel[1]{\parbox[c][1cm][c]{3cm}{#1\strut}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(8.5,3)(-1,0)
  \put(0,1){\line(0,1){1}}
  \put(3,1){\line(0,1){1}}
  \put(6,1){\line(0,1){1}}
  \put(0,0.6){\mycenter{$K$}}
  \put(0,2.2){\mycenter{$L$}}
  \put(3,0.6){\mycenter{$\mathfrak{p}$}}
  \put(3,2.2){\mycenter{$\mathfrak{P}$}}
  \put(6,0.6){\mycenter{$R_K/\mathfrak{p}$}}
  \put(6,2.2){\mycenter{$R_L/\mathfrak{P}$}}
  \put(0.1,1.35){\mylabel{finite\\extension}}
  \put(3.1,1.35){\mylabel{unramified\\prime}}
  \put(6.1,1.35){\mylabel{extension of\\finite fields}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]